# Weight Initialization from pretrained BERT error in pytorch

Tags: nlp, pytorch, multilabel-classification, pre-trained-model, spacy-transformers

I am trying to train the model using pretrained model(BERT) using pytorch. The pretrained model weights still arent accepted.

I see this error:

```
Weights of BertForMultiLable not initialized from pretrained model: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
Weights from pretrained model not used in BertForMultiLable: ['cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias']
```

Here is the complete traceback:

```
Training/evaluation parameters Namespace(adam_epsilon=1e-08, arch='bert', data_name='ICD9', do_data=False, do_lower_case=True, do_test=False, do_train=True, epochs=6, eval_batch_size=8, eval_max_seq_len=256, fp16=False, fp16_opt_level='O1', grad_clip=1.0, gradient_accumulation_steps=1, learning_rate=2e-05, local_rank=-1, loss_scale=0, mode='min', monitor='valid_loss', n_gpu='0', resume_path='', save_best=True, seed=42, sorted=1, train_batch_size=8, train_max_seq_len=256, valid_size=0.2, warmup_proportion=0.1, weight_decay=0.01)
Loading examples from cached file pybert/dataset/cached_train_examples_bert
Loading features from cached file pybert/dataset/cached_train_features_256_bert
sorted data by th length of input
Loading examples from cached file pybert/dataset/cached_valid_examples_bert
Loading features from cached file pybert/dataset/cached_valid_features_256_bert
initializing model
loading configuration file pybert/pretrain/bert/base-uncased/config.json
Model config {
  "attention_probs_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "finetuning_task": null,
  "hidden_act": "gelu",
  "hidden_dropout_prob": 0.1,
  "hidden_size": 768,
  "initializer_range": 0.02,
  "intermediate_size": 3072,
  "is_decoder": false,
  "layer_norm_eps": 1e-12,
  "max_position_embeddings": 512,
  "num_attention_heads": 12,
  "num_hidden_layers": 12,
  "num_labels": 19,
  "output_attentions": false,
  "output_hidden_states": false,
  "output_past": true,
  "pruned_heads": {},
  "torchscript": false,
  "type_vocab_size": 2,
  "use_bfloat16": false,
  "vocab_size": 28996
}

loading weights file pybert/pretrain/bert/base-uncased/pytorch_model.bin
Weights of BertForMultiLable not initialized from pretrained model: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
Weights from pretrained model not used in BertForMultiLable: ['cls.predictions.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.dense.bias', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.weight', 'cls.predictions.transform.LayerNorm.bias', 'cls.predictions.decoder.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.weight', 'cls.seq_relationship.bias']
initializing callbacks
***** Running training *****
  Num examples = 21479
  Num Epochs = 6
  Total train batch size (w. parallel, distributed & accumulation) = 8
  Gradient Accumulation steps = 1
  Total optimization steps = 16110
Warning: There's no GPU available on this machine, training will be performed on CPU.
Warning: The number of GPU's configured to use is 0, but only 0 are available on this machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_bert.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "run_bert.py", line 220, in main
    run_train(args)
  File "run_bert.py", line 125, in run_train
    trainer.train(train_data=train_dataloader, valid_data=valid_dataloader, seed=args.seed)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/bert_pytorch/pybert/train/trainer.py", line 168, in train
    summary(self.model,*(input_ids, segment_ids,input_mask),show_input=True)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/bert_pytorch/pybert/common/tools.py", line 307, in summary
    model(*inputs)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/virtualenvs/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/bert_pytorch/pybert/model/nn/bert_for_multi_label.py", line 14, in forward
    outputs = self.bert(input_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids,attention_mask=attention_mask, head_mask=head_mask)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/virtualenvs/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/virtualenvs/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/transformers/modeling_bert.py", line 722, in forward
    embedding_output = self.embeddings(input_ids=input_ids, position_ids=position_ids, token_type_ids=token_type_ids, inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/virtualenvs/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 533, in __call__
    result = hook(self, input)
  File "/home/aditya_vartak/bert_pytorch/pybert/common/tools.py", line 269, in hook
    summary[m_key]["input_shape"] = list(input[0].size())
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? I have a similar issue right now with my own PyTorch models.

Answer (score 2):

for the Error you cited, actually I think that is only a Warning that states you  you are loading on your architecture `BertForMultiLable` the `Weights from pretrained model` that was not trained for that specific tasks.
Similar warning discussion [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5421)

The real error here it's another: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. but for that you should attach some code and more information about what you are doing .